# What is the solution of this error Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans, terminal

I want to run my Java code in terminal (ubuntu Linux)

I faced this error:

> Could not find or load main class

```
package javaapplication7;

public class CannyEdgeDetectorSeq {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

and i used the command:

```
javac  CannyEdgeDetectorSeq.java
java CannyEdgeDetectorSeq
```

how I can run my code? maybe I missed some thing likes define jar file????

Comment: can u share entire code.

Comment: `java -cp . javaapplication7.CannyEdgeDetectorSeq`

Comment: Have you checked if a CannyEdgeDetectorSeq.class was created after `javac  CannyEdgeDetectorSeq.java`

Comment: @Balasubramanian it's a long code

Comment: @igor
 
yes it's created in the same path

Comment: @M. le Rutte  enter this command after javac ?

Comment: Maybe start with an [introductionary tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/unix.html)?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run a single class, you don't need a package declaration, only class declaration:

```
public class CannyEdgeDetectorSeq
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    }
}
```

If you want to specify a package, then you must put the original source code in a sub-folder named javaapplication7, and then, from the root directory:

```
javac javaapplication7/CannyEdgeDetectorSeq.java
java javaapplication7.CannyEdgeDetectorSeq
```

Comment: this class have many function, i tried i got the same error